# Dahdi configuration for more than one digium  card in a single machine

Tags: asterisk, telephony

How to configure the more than one digium card in the single machine. I need the configuration in the system.conf file. I have configured. But it is not working correctly. First card is working. Second card is not working.

Comment: Have you configured Chan_dahdi?

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit fuzzy. This is a system.conf for 2 4Port Cards.
The file has been created by /usr/sbin/dahdi_genconf (+ some modifications after)
***Note:*** command all driver in /etc/dahdi/modules you don't need. It produce sometimes problems.

```
# ***************************************************************************
# Span 1: TE4/0/1 "T4XXP (PCI) Card 0 Span 1" (MASTER) HDB3/CCS/CRC4 ClockSource 
# span=1,1,0,ccs,hdb3,crc4
span=1,0,0,ccs,hdb3,crc4
# termtype: te
bchan=1-15,17-31
dchan=16
echocanceller=mg2,1-15,17-31

# ***************************************************************************
# Span 2: TE4/0/2 "T4XXP (PCI) Card 0 Span 2" HDB3/CCS/CRC4 
span=2,0,0,ccs,hdb3,crc4
# termtype: te
bchan=32-46,48-62
dchan=47
echocanceller=mg2,32-46,48-62

# ***************************************************************************
# PSTN
# Span 3: TE4/0/3 "T4XXP (PCI) Card 0 Span 3" HDB3/CCS/CRC4 
# span=3,3,0,ccs,hdb3,crc4
span=3,1,0,ccs,hdb3,crc4
# termtype: te
bchan=63-77,79-93
dchan=78
echocanceller=mg2,63-77,79-93

# ***************************************************************************
# Span 4: TE4/0/4 "T4XXP (PCI) Card 0 Span 4" HDB3/CCS/CRC4 
# span=4,4,0,ccs,hdb3,crc4
span=4,0,0,ccs,hdb3,crc4
# termtype: te
bchan=94-108,110-124
dchan=109
echocanceller=mg2,94-108,110-124

# Span 5: TE4/1/1 "T4XXP (PCI) Card 1 Span 1" HDB3/CCS/CRC4 RED
span=5,0,0,ccs,hdb3,crc4
# termtype: te
bchan=125-139,141-155
dchan=140
echocanceller=mg2,125-139,141-155

# Span 6: TE4/1/2 "T4XXP (PCI) Card 1 Span 2" HDB3/CCS/CRC4 RED
span=6,0,0,ccs,hdb3,crc4
# termtype: te
bchan=156-170,172-186
dchan=171
echocanceller=mg2,156-170,172-186

# Span 7: TE4/1/3 "T4XXP (PCI) Card 1 Span 3" HDB3/CCS/CRC4 RED
span=7,0,0,ccs,hdb3,crc4
# termtype: te
bchan=187-201,203-217
dchan=202
echocanceller=mg2,187-201,203-217

# Span 8: TE4/1/4 "T4XXP (PCI) Card 1 Span 4" HDB3/CCS/CRC4 RED
span=8,0,0,ccs,hdb3,crc4
# termtype: te
bchan=218-232,234-248
dchan=233
echocanceller=mg2,218-232,234-248

# Global data

loadzone    = de
defaultzone = de
```